# How to add a title to a plot with both left-justified and right-justified text

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve, but by using `PerformanceAnalytics`.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

data(edhec)
chart.TimeSeries(edhec)
```

This gives the graph:
[image: Nice graph]
You can see that the title has both **Convertible Arbitrage** left-justified and the date right-justified, *within the main panel of the plot* which is the standard for the "pre-ggplot" R quant packages (see e.g. `quantmod`).

My question is how to do this with `ggplot2`, in either the `title` or `subtitle` of the plot?

**Edit.** Clarified exactly what I am asking for with regards to text justification.

Answer (score 2):

You could manually `cowplot::draw_text`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = "")

ggdraw(p) +
    draw_text("Miles/gallon vs. weight (in 1000 lbs)", x = 0.01, y = 0.99, hjust = 0, vjust = 1) + 
    draw_text("Dataset: mtcars", x = 0.99, y = 0.99, hjust = 1, vjust = 1)
```

[image]

The `labs(title = "")` is necessary to create empty space for the title.

Comment: Close! But not exactly what I wanted, which was the alignment in @yarnabrina's answer. Do you know how to get the x value of the y-axis? That would do it.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn I am not sure how this is *not* what you wanted. The plot has two "titles", one left and one right justified. This is the same as in the base R answer. I don't think you can use `ggtitle` for this, so you need to manually add the text. This is quite straightforward. I don't understand what you mean by "how to get the x value of the y-axis?".

Comment: Perhaps it would help if I showed the `ggplot` I was trying to add the title to, but surely you can see the difference between your title and the one in @yarnabrina 's anwer? In the latter, the title is aligned with the *panel*, and not the while plot. I'm not just being picky. I have sever panels stacked on top of each other, and it looks terrible if they are not consistent.

Comment: P.S. I put the question abut the x value of the y-axis as a new entry in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484229/how-can-you-get-the-coordinates-of-components-of-a-ggplot

Comment: @JamesHirschorn I don't understand or perhaps you're missing my point. You can simply change `x = 0.01` to e.g. `x = 0.07` to align the text with a particular feature of the plot panel.

Comment: yes, that is exactly my point. How do get x value of the y-axis? for the third time. I won't repeat it again. And no, "eyeballing it" isn't an adequate answer.

Comment: @JamesHischorn "I won't repeat it again." What are you on about? You ask strangers on the internet for free help and meet them with rude attitude? Your tone is not acceptable on SO.

Comment: I do appreciate your help. I'm the one that upvoted your answer, btw. Sorry, for the tone, but I frustrated because I believe you were being a bit "dense", since you ask "what I am on about".